# Finding domain of implicit functions.

Tags: functions

Suppose $f(x,y)=k$ where k is a constant. I am supposed to find the domain of $ f(x,y)=1$ so should I check for the value of $x $where $f(x,y)$ is defined or first write $ y=f(x) $and then find the values of x for which f(x) is defined. Consider $x^{2y}=1$. The domain will be all real x I think but the answer in my book is given as only $x>0 $or $ x=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given function
$$f(x,y):=x^{2y}$$
has as domain the right half plane $$H:=\bigl\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\bigm| x>0, \ -\infty<y<\infty\bigr\}\ ,$$
because as soon as you consider powers $b^t$ with variable noninteger exponents the base $b$ is automatically restricted to ${\mathbb R}_{>0}$.

Let's see whether the equation $f(x,y)=1$, i.e., $x^{2y}=1$, "defines $y$ as a function of $x$" in some way. Note that by definition $$1=x^{2y}:=\exp(2y\log x)\ ,$$ and as $\exp$ is monotonically increasing this is equivalent with $2y\log x=0$. It follows that
$$y=0\quad\vee\quad \log x=0,\quad{\rm resp.,}\quad y=0\quad\vee\quad  x=1\ .$$
In other words the solution set $$\bigl\{(x,y)\in H\bigm| f(x,y)=1\bigr\}$$
consists of the horizontal half line $y=0$ together with the vertical line $x=1$.

We therefore can say the following: The given equation defines implicitly the function $y=\phi(x):\equiv0$ separately in the $x$-intervals $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=-1,\;y=1/2.$  Then $x^{2y}=-1$ and not $1.$  Given any negative $x$-value you can choose a $y$ which makes the equality fail.

Comment: But there can be certain y for which it satisfies the equation right. I think that at x=-1 y should be equal to any integer right?